# Is it possible to transfer a 401(a) from one brokerage to another?

Tags: united-states, ira, rollover

I created a rollover IRA at Schwab, and am trying to transfer the account, but it seems a bit more difficult than I thought.

When I create a rollover IRA from Schwab, and try to transfer the Fidelity account, it asks me what type of account I am trying to transfer.... and i don't see 401(a) as an option.

Which one do I select?

[image: a list of options from the schwab account rollover page]

Comment: You'll have to call them and ask. What does "None Of the above" mean?

Answer (score 2):

So I called them and they said just select Rollover IRA... hope that helps anyone else who wants to do that in the future.